# Android in-app billing: как проверить статус покупки?

Tags: android

Я пытаюсь использовать сервис покупок внутри приложений.
Проблема состоит в том, что я не знаю как проверить, куплен ли данный предмет на данном аккаунте. Это нужно на тот случай, если пользователь сменит телефон или сделает хард-ресет, и т. п. Мне нужно узнать статус предмета (куплен и ли не куплен) именно из плей маркета, а не с локальной базы данных.

Так же я использую [robotmedia / AndroidBillingLibrary](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary) для упрощения процесса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь опцией [RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html). Позволяет получить историю операций/покупок клиента - по сути выдергивает записи из Play Market'а

Comment: Спасибо за верное направление!